# Cannot start appium when docker container starts

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile, appium

I'm setting up a docker images that consist of centos:7.6.1810, npm, appium, and oracle jdk 8

i want to everytime the container runs, the appium server executed automatically and pushed back to the background. so this is what i wrote on the end of my `Dockerfile`:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "appium", "&"]
```

when i run the container, the container and appium failed to start, and returns this on container log:

```
/usr/bin/appium: line 2: use strict: command not found
/usr/bin/appium: appium: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/usr/bin/appium: appium: line 4: `var _interopRequireWildcard = require("@babel/runtime/helpers/interopRequireWildcard");'
```

is that the correct command to start appium automatically when the container starts?

note: i'm installing the appium using npm, using `npm install -g appium --allow-root --unsafe-perm=true` on my Dockerfile and got `appium@1.13.0` and using node version `v12.2.0`on my machine

Comment: Containers typically run one job _in the foreground_.  If you have multiple processes you need to run, best practice is to run them in multiple containers.

Comment: This isn't a container problem, or a docker problem. You just don't know how to run appium. Change the entrypoint to bash, then run the container locally and you'll end up on a bash prompt -- use that to learn how to start apium. Also, listen to @DavidMaze's comment -- you're also doing the wrong thing. And, finally, there is an appium image on docker hub: https://hub.docker.com/r/appium/appium

Comment: @EngineerDollery ah okay, will try that first, thanks